# Batch files are not running properly on IIS 8

Tags: batch-file, iis, azure, web-applications, windows-server

I'm trying to host a web application on Azure VM. The website uses some batch files (.bat) to run some tasks. I realized there might be some issue with .bat files, so I tried to fix the issue:

Windows Server 2012 R2

IIS 8

1) Set the "Identity" of "Application Pool" to "LocalSystem"

2) Convert the .bat files to .exe and made sure it's x64 since the OS is the same

3) Give the "Full Control" permission to "EVERYONE"

4) Edit Permissions in "Handler Mapping" to allow for executable files

5) Registered the .exe and it's .dll files in "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions"

If I double click on the .exe files, they will run properly. But when I'm accessing them through the website, the .exe file appears in task manager, but nothing will happen.

I would appreciate any suggesstion.

Answer (score 0):

I won't get into why what you're proposing poses numerous security issues, but you may want to look into how to grant the IIS service the ability to interact with the desktop. This is commonly done by granting the IIS Admin service the permission through the Services MMC.

Comment: I did allow IIS service the ability to interact with the desktop; however, I'm still having the same issue. I did more research on what you suggested and apparently I have to let ASP.NET worker interact with desktop or allow ASP.NET worker process to run in SYSTEM account. I'm having trouble doing that though.